# Select rows from a table where row in another table with same id has a particular value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

In MySQL:

If we have two tables:

```
comments
key    |    value
=================
1      |    foo
2      |    bar
3      |    foobar
4      |    barfoo
```

and:

```
meta
comment_key    |    value
=========================
1              |    1
2              |    1
3              |    2
4              |    1
```

I want to get the comments from the `comment` table that have a corresponding `comment_key` in the `meta` table that have a specific `value` (the `value` column in the `meta` table).

For example, I'd like to select all the rows from the `comment` table that have a `value` of `1` in the `meta` table:

I'd expect these results:

```
key    |    value
=================
1      |    foo
2      |    bar
4      |    barfoo
```

And if I were to select all the rows from the `comment` table that have a `value` of `2` in the `meta` table:

I'd expect this result:

```
key    |    value
=================
3      |    foobar
```

I really hope someone can help, thank you all in advance!

I think I need to do a join? Any pointers would be great, and if at all possible, a short explanation so I can work out where I was going wrong -> so I'll know for next time!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I actually wouldn't recommend a JOIN for this — or rather, I'd recommend a "[semijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin)", which is a relational-algebra concept not directly expressed in SQL. A semijoin is essentially a join where you want to retrieve records from only one table, but with the proviso that they have corresponding records in a different table.

In SQL notation, this concept is expressed indirectly, by using [an `IN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html), with a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT key, value
  FROM comments
 WHERE key IN
        ( SELECT comment_key
            FROM meta
           WHERE value = 1
        )
;
```

(MySQL will actually end up translating that back into a semijoin internally — essentially a sort of degenerate inner-join — but the `IN` clause is the natural way to express it in raw SQL.)

Comment: correction - it doesn't matter if a `join`, `exists` or `in` predicates are used, they are all Semi Joins - defined as joins that return rows from one table based on the existence of related rows in another table.

Comment: @JCooper: I don't see it that way. Suppose that for every record in `parent`, there are zero, one, or more than one records in `child`. Then a semi-join would include zero or one copies of every `parent` record, whereas a SQL `INNER JOIN` would include multiple copies of some `parent` records. But I can see it your way. In relational algebra, a semi-join is equivalent to an inner-join followed by an appropriate projection; so we can take this to be a difference between SQL `SELECT` and relational-algebra projections rather than between SQL `INNER JOIN` and relational-algebra semi-joins.

Comment: Wow, I was so close, i just had `=` instead of `IN`! Thank you, works a treat!

Comment: I had the exact same problem ruakh of duplicate rows from using the join method. It feels weird that join can't resolve the duplicate rows problem.

Comment: How would this compare with using the simple join but then running distinct to make sure it is unique?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Technically speaking, an `INNER JOIN` plus `DISTINCT` is not necessarily equivalent to using an `IN` clause, since the latter only ensures that you have at most one result-set row per table row, which can still result in duplicates if the table itself contains duplicates. (For example, `SELECT first_name FROM t1 WHERE last_name IN (SELECT last_name FROM t2)` will probably have duplicates, whereas `SELECT DISTINCT t1.first_name FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.last_name = t2.last_name` cannot.) But for a typical case, like the OP's, where one of the fields in the field-list is *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* a primary key, and therefore guaranteed not to be a duplicate *anyway*, the two approaches are semantically equivalent, and would very likely have identical performance. (You might want to try both, though, and see if one performs better on your DBMS with your data.)

Comment: Yep I still have a primary id. But since I'm using Codeigniter, it feels easier to use distinct than running with a subquery. Basically the situation was with an ideas table, and each idea could have multiple tags in tags table.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I don't see what using CodeIgniter has to do with anything, but if you want to use `INNER JOIN` plus `DISTINCT`, that is certainly your right. As I said in my answer, I don't think that's the natural way to express this, but if you disagree, then there's no reason you have to substitute my judgment for your own.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a plain, vanilla equi-join here.

```
SELECT `comment`.`key`   AS `key`,
       `comment`.`value` AS `value`
    FROM `comments` 
        JOIN `meta` 
            ON `comments`.`key` = `meta`.`comment_key` 
    WHERE `meta`.`value` = 1;
```

I'm not really sure what sort of advice you're looking for here but you can read more about the topic (not MySQL specific) at [Wikipedia's SQL JOIN page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join)

I'd recommend indexing on `comment`.`key` and `meta`.`comment_key` with both being PRIMARY KEY indexes assuming that you want there to only be 1 `meta` row per `comment` row (PRIMARY KEYs are UNIQUE by definition). If you want to allow more than 1 `meta` per `comment` then add a separate index `id` column to `meta` and make that the PRIMARY KEY with `comment_key` just a b-tree index.

I'm also not sure how the performance of this will compare to the "semi-join" answer also listed but, to me, this is the simpler and more natural way to express the query; with only two tables, though, it shouldn't be too challenging for MySQL to optimize.

Comment: I'm not sure if mentioning indexes is over stepping the question inappropriately or not. I've just seen too many programmers fail to consider them since the queries always run fast on the testing data with a dozen rows per table or less.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in duplicate rows in the parent if there are multiple child rows?

Answer (score 0):

I would use "INNER JOIN" in the following way:

```
SELECT comments.key, comments.value FROM comments 
INNER JOIN meta ON comments.key=meta.comment_key WHERE meta.value = 1;
```

Cheers! ;-)